# How to insert row in HTML tablesorter table body in javascript/node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I have made a function test tool for my company app using html/css/javascript/node.js/express/tablesorter.

My test tool is successfully performed the function tests.

My table style is from opensource 'Tablesorter'.

[image]

This is edit screen. The file is .ejs format. So, Node.js server render the file to html dynamically.

But, I wonder how to insert the row additionally in this table. So, I searched to solve the problem and got some solution like below.

```js
 for (var i in rList) {
  var table = document.getElementById("ID_Table");
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);
  var list = rList[i].split(" ");
  cell1.innerHTML = list[0];
  cell2.innerHTML = list[1];
 }
```

But, this way is incomplete. The result is like this.

[image]

The 'tablesorter' style is not applied to additional rows. I don't know how to solve this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
 <!-- Character Set -->
 <meta charset="utf-8">

 <!-- Title -->
 <title><%= title %></title>
 
 <!-- Style -->
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/>
 
 <!-- JS -->
 <script src="/javascripts/indexCore.js"></script>

 <!-- jQuery -->
 <script src="/opensources/tablesorter/docs/js/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/opensources/tablesorter/docs/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  
 <!-- Tablesorter: theme -->
 <link class="theme default" rel="stylesheet" href="/opensources/tablesorter/css/theme.default.css">
 <link class="theme blue" rel="stylesheet" href="/opensources/tablesorter/css/theme.blue.css">
 <link class="theme green" rel="stylesheet" href="/opensources/tablesorter/css/theme.green.css">
 <link class="theme grey" rel="stylesheet" href="/opensources/tablesorter/css/theme.grey.css">
 <link class="theme ice" rel="stylesheet" href="/opensources/tablesorter/css/theme.ice.css">
 <link class="theme black-ice" rel="stylesheet" href="/opensources/tablesorter/css/theme.black-ice.css">
 <link class="theme dark" rel="stylesheet" href="/opensources/tablesorter/css/theme.dark.css">
 <link class="theme dropbox" rel="stylesheet" href="/opensources/tablesorter/css/theme.dropbox.css">
 <link class="theme metro-dark" rel="stylesheet" href="/opensources/tablesorter/css/theme.metro-dark.css">

 <!-- Tablesorter script: required -->
 <script src="/opensources/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
 <script src="/opensources/tablesorter/js/widgets/widget-filter.js"></script>
 <script src="/opensources/tablesorter/js/widgets/widget-stickyHeaders.js"></script>

 <script id="js">
 $(function(){
  /* make second table scroll within its wrapper */
  $('#ID_Table').tablesorter({
   widthFixed : true,
   headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', // Add icon for various themes
   widgets: [ 'zebra', 'stickyHeaders', 'filter' ],
   widgetOptions: {
    // jQuery selector or object to attach sticky header to
    stickyHeaders_attachTo : '.wrapper' // or $('.wrapper')
   }
  });
  
  $("#ID_Table tbody").click(function () {
   //$(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
   //alert('a'); 
  });
 });
 </script>

 <script>
 $(function() { //이 부분은 렌더링 되자마자 실행되는 부분
  window.includeCaption = true;
  $('.caption').on('click', function(){
   includeCaption = !includeCaption;
   $(this).html( '' + includeCaption );
   $('#ID_Table').each(function(){
    if (this.config) {
     this.config.widgetOptions.stickyHeaders_includeCaption = includeCaption;
     this.config.widgetOptions.$sticky.children('caption').toggle(includeCaption);
    }
   });
  });

  // removed jQuery UI theme because of the accordion!
  $('link.theme').each(function(){ this.disabled = true; });
  
  var themes = 'dropbox blue green grey ice black-ice dark default metro-dark', //테마 순서
   i, o = '', t = themes.split(' ');
  for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
   o += '<option value="' + t[i] + '">' + t[i] + '</option>';
  }
  
  $('select:first')
   .append(o)
   .change(function(){
    var theme = $(this).val().toLowerCase(),
     // ui-theme is added by the themeswitcher
     files = $('link.theme').each(function(){
      this.disabled = true;
     })
    files.filter('.' + theme).each(function(){
     this.disabled = false;
    });
    $('table')
     .removeClass('tablesorter-' + t.join(' tablesorter-'))
     .addClass('tablesorter-' + (theme === 'black-ice' ? 'blackice' : theme) );
   }).change();
 });
 </script>
    </head>
 
    <body>
 <div id="header">
  <h1><%= title %></h1>
  <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
  
  <a href="/screenMain" id="screenMain">Main</a>
  <a href="/screenEdit" id="screenEdit">Edit</a>
  <a href="/" id="screenBlank">Blank</a>
  <hr/>
 </div>

 
 
 <div id="wrap">
  <div id="Main_Screen">
   <input type="button" value="로딩" id="btn" onclick="dynamicLoadScript_Main('/temps/MainScript.js', '/temps/WrapScript.js')"></input>
   <input type="button" value="수행" id="btn1" onclick="Automation()"></input>
   <button type="button">결과 리스트 출력</button>
  </div>
  
  <div id="List_Screen" class="narrow-block wrapper">
  Theme: <select></select>
  <table id="ID_Table" class="tablesorter" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
   <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Function</th>
    <th>Result</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
 </div>
  
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my .ejs File.

And, this is printResult Function in indexCore.js.

```js
function printResult(){
 var rList = resultList.split('\n');
 
 for (var i in rList) {
  var table = document.getElementById("ID_Table");
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var list = rList[i].split(" ");
  cell1.innerHTML = list[0];
  cell2.innerHTML = list[1];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit and apply your logic at the `.ejs` file directly at your backend as your client side solution seems to be run after table being initialized by `Tablesorter`. You can also try to implement your client side solution adding the rows to table first then initialize `Tablesorter`. Good Luck!

Comment: Umm... I try to understand your hint but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: could you give me the hint more detail? plz.

Comment: Sure, edit your question and show me your .ejs file @Fortuneman

Comment: I edit my question and I show you my .ejs file and .js code.

Comment: You need to run `printResult()` (which adds rows) first then `$('#ID_Table').tablesorter({..});`  (the initialization statement)

Comment: But, printResult() can not run first. It is always called after ('#ID_Table').tablesorter({..}); So I want to know how to run printResult() after ('#ID_Table').tablesorter({..}); Is it impossible?

Comment: `printResult()` has no dependencies except for the table element (which already exists in the page) and `resultList` which doesn't depend on `tablesorter`, So I don't see any problem to run `printResult` first